# How to add image to $flow.files without uploading through using ngFlow plugin for angualrjs

Tags: angularjs, ng-flow

Here is my HTML markup for uploading of an avatar:

```
<div  style="padding: 10px;">
  <div class="text-center">
    <h4><kbd>Avatar Picture</kbd></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail" ng-hide="obj.flow.files.length">
    <img src="Some url for none avatar picture."/>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail" ng-show="obj.flow.files.length">
    <img flow-img="obj.flow.files[0]"/>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <span class="btn btn-info" ng-hide="obj.flow.files.length" flow-btn
                              flow-attrs="{accept:'image/*'}">Select image</span>
    <span class="btn btn-info" ng-show="obj.flow.files.length" flow-btn
                              flow-attrs="{accept:'image/*'}">Change</span>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" ng-show="obj.flow.files.length"
       ng-click="obj.flow.cancel()">Remove</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to add image if the user has avatar (without request sending). Using $scope.$flow.addFile() is a bad idea I think.

I mean if the user have an avatar and obj.flow.files[0] should not be empty, because need to show his avatar.

Comment: Fixed grammar and code block.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop flow from uploading on file add, use the following to prevent this default behavior. You should still have access to the files in obj.flow.files[0], but it will only be temporarily stored (not uploaded to server).

```
$scope.$on('flow::fileAdded', function (event, $flow, flowFile) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

For example, to ignore files that are larger than a certain file size, I do this (otherwise, continue upload).

```
$scope.$on('flow::fileAdded', function (event, $flow, flowFile) {

    if(flowFile.size > 5000000) {
        $scope.errorText = "Error: File too large.";
        //prevent file from uploading
        event.preventDefault();
    } else {
        // Upload file.
        $flow.upload(); 
    }
});
```

Hopefully I understood your question correctly.